# Python Pandas: Create continuous id values using "flag values" in a df column and displaying it in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, grouping

I have a very big dataframe (20.000.000+ rows) that containes a column called 'sequence' amongst others.

The 'sequence' column is calculated from a time series applying a few conditional statements. The value "2" flags the start of a sequence, the value "3" flags the end of a sequence, the value "1" flags a datapoint within the sequence and the value "4" flags datapoints that need to be ignored. (Note: the flag values doesn't necessarily have to be 1,2,3,4)

What I want to achieve is a continous ID value (written in a seperate column - see 'desired_Id_Output' in the example below) that labels the slices of sequences from 2 - 3 in a unique fashion (the length of a sequence is variable ranging from 2 [Start+End only] to 5000+ datapoints) to be able to do further groupby-calculations on the individual sequences.

```
index  sequence    desired_Id_Output    
0          2                  1                   
1          1                  1                   
2          1                  1                   
3          1                  1                   
4          1                  1                   
5          3                  1                   
6          2                  2                   
7          1                  2                   
8          1                  2                   
9          3                  2                   
10         4                  NaN                   
11         4                  NaN                   
12         2                  3                   
13         3                  3
```

Thanks in advance and BR!

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything better than the "dumb" solution of looping through the entire thing, something like this:

```
import numpy as np    

counter = 0
tmp = np.empty_like(df['sequence'].values, dtype=np.float)

for i in range(len(tmp)):
    if df['sequence'][i] == 4:
        tmp[i] = np.nan
    else:
        if df['sequence'][i] == 2:
            counter += 1
        tmp[i] = counter
df['desired_Id_output'] = tmp
```

Of course this is going to be pretty slow with a 20M-sized DataFrame. One way to improve this is via just-in-time compilation with `numba`:

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def foo(sequence):
    # put in appropriate modification of the above code block
    return tmp
```

and call this with argument `df['sequence'].values`.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply and your presented solution!

Comment: I was hoping for a "function approach" that could be maped or applyed to the entire column vector, but your code is still way faster than my amateurish attempt with .iterrows().

Comment: It's generally faster to do it like this: extracting the columns via `.values`, passing that to a function that is optimised for numpy arrays (esp. when you can do it with `numba`), then setting the dataframe column to the function output. Mapping and applying on dataframe columns is generally slow.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work to count the sequence starts? And then just set the ignore values (flag `4`) afterwards. Like this:

```
sequence_starts = df.sequence == 2
sequence_ignore = df.sequence == 4
sequence_id = sequence_starts.cumsum()
sequence_id[sequence_ignore] = numpy.nan
```